# How to hide autodidacts in college?

Tags: education

I'm writing about a US reality tv show, which takes famous autodidacts  and sends them to study college in their own respective field. The comedy is to see how they will fair. What would their teachers & fellow students think about them without knowing who they really are.

My assumption is that college administration works together with the producers to issue them required documents.

Also when necessary make up artists and disguises are used to make them unrecognizable.
.

Since autodidacts are usually older then typical student, usually in their late 20s or mid 30s, what would be plausible explanations why they are in college that they should use for their professors & fellow students?

Example episode would be a director who dropped from high school, but made many successful movies and was nominated or won for directing awards, being sent undercover to learn how to make movies with newbies.

Or multiplatinum jazz musician, who wrote many acclaimed albums being sent to study jazz composition.

Or writer of several bestsellers studying writing.

TL;DR: How would 30 something plausibly explain why they're doing college to their professors & fellow students?

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, Xing Pei! If you have a moment, please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. You may also find [meta] and [The Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) (both of which require 5 rep to post on) useful. [Here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6388) is a meta post on the culture and style of Worldbuilding.SE, just to help you understand our scope and methods, and how we do things here. Have fun!

Comment: It's not exactly rare to start college a little later.  I don't think they'd need much of an explanation.  Maybe they could say they couldn't afford it previously, but they've saved up enough cash now, or something similar.

Comment: The premise makes no sense.  If they're famous it would take the average college student about 35 seconds to find them and verify their ID on the internet.  They can't hide.  Make up won't help as they'd have to wear it practically all day every day (and maybe evening).  They'd also need to have a massive and well rehearsed [legend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espionage#Organization) which is just not supportable by most people so they could mix normally.  Once they start lying or making mistakes in that story people will rapidly get very suspicious.

Comment: To add to @StephenG's comment, what would be the point of sending people who are overqualified for the undergrad work taking undergrad classes?  This isn't like corporate bosses who haven't actually flipped burgers in their lives.  These are people who will be known as too smart for the class in a day or two (unless they never say a thing) and are likely to be very arrogant.  Instructors would have them removed from classes in minutes unless forced to deal with it - and I don't see that happening.  What's your goal with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Colleges and universities in the USA serve a wide variety of students from many backgrounds...including a variety of ages and career goals. So there's generally no need to hide anything from anybody.

Older students in USA colleges and universities are somewhat common due to career retraining, military service, and other reasons. This is somewhat different from advanced education culture in some other parts of the world.

Having been both a 20-something undergraduate and a 30-something undergraduate (again) in USA universities, I never had to explain anything to any fellow students. I never asked older students why they were there, and no younger students ever asked me.

Of course, we didn't socialize much - older students often already have families, friends, jobs, and other great reasons to not hang out with much younger, immature folks.

I found older students more likely to ask questions and to be better prepared for classes. Professors never asked older students why they were there (none of their business anyway), and were happy to have well-prepared students in their classes.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this persons are getting 2nd education? 
i know person who has medical education from 19 to 25 years, and in 30+ years he received 4 years bachelor degree of Applied Physics and Mathematics. It was in Soviet Union.

Its quite unusual, but students become comfortable with much older persons among them quite fast.